# I'm having to do a lot of array accessing every time I want to access a variable in a Virtual Machine I'm writing. Is there a better way?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, virtual-machine

I'm writing a virtual machine for my own programming language, in C.
For the following code snippet:

- instructionQueue[] is the sequential list of instructions to be executed as well as their arguments
- instructionHead is the index of the current instruction being executed (in the example, it's the location of an argument to a function, ie a variable).
- callStack[] is a stack of functions called and the addresses of their variables
- variables[] is an array with all the actual variables values (including things which take up multiple slots like vectors).

Basically, every time I access a variable such as to perform an operation, I use a macro which is defined something like this:

```
variables[callStack[instructionQueue[instructionHead] + functionOffset]]
```

So *every single time* I want to access a variable to use it as part of an operation, the VM has to do three array accesses, which seems quite inefficient.  Am I going about this all wrong?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Use pointers. And you should certainly maintain a pointer to the current stack frame.

Comment: As always, it's best to profile before spending a lot of effort optimising. However, using pointers instead of array indices is often a good idea. (For example, for the instruction pointer and maybe the current stack top.)

Comment: Depending on the possible optimizations, the compiler might have done already what can be done, for example cache some of the intermediate values. As @rici says, before putting a lot of work into manual optimization, profile your program. -- Commonly only a change in architecture or algorithm leads to better performance.